# mac cannot bootup Mac OS X

Tags: macos, windows, dual-boot

Installation of Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro prompts me that it requires a CD/DVD device driver.

I ejected my DVD and then got a window displaying "No bootable device--inset boot disk and press any key."

But, I would like to return to Mac OS X only. So, how do I boot back into Mac OS X.

Comment: It's not very clear what your problem is? Was Mac OS X installed and working before? Did you possibly erase the Mac partition while trying to install Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is awfully unclear, but I can answer the last part. Try holding <kbd>option</kbd> during start up. It'll display a list of the currently available devices you can boot off of, one of which should be your Mac OS X hard drive partition, unless you somehow overwrote it